# SQL Getting unique list and replace nulls

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working on some data that is structured like this

| userid | useremail | username | sessionId | eventTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | joe | 1 | 2021-01-27 21:03:03.2500000 |
| 123 | joe@me.com |  | 1 | 2021-01-27 21:05:03.2500000 |
| 123 | joe@me.com | joe | 1 | 2021-01-27 21:03:03.2500000 |
|  | joe@me.com |  | 2 | 2021-01-26 21:05:03.2500000 |
| 123 | joe@me.com | joe | 2 | 2021-01-26 21:03:03.2500000 |
| 123 |  | joe | 2 | 2021-01-26 21:05:03.2500000 |
|  | joe@me.com | joe | 2 | 2021-01-26 21:03:03.2500000 |
| 123 |  |  | 2 | 2021-01-26 21:05:03.2500000 |

So basically userid, usermail, or username can be blank, but sessionId is always populated. I want to be able to get a result set that has each row, but with the missing fields populated. I can assume at least one of the 3 user fields is populated, otherwise I don't care.

Like this

| userid | useremail | username | sessionId | eventTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | joe@me.com | joe | 1 | 2021-01-27 21:03:03.2500000 |
| 123 | joe@me.com | joe | 1 | 2021-01-27 21:05:03.2500000 |
| 123 | joe@me.com | joe | 1 | 2021-01-27 21:03:03.2500000 |
| 123 | joe@me.com | joe | 2 | 2021-01-26 21:05:03.2500000 |
| 123 | joe@me.com | joe | 2 | 2021-01-26 21:03:03.2500000 |
| 123 | joe@me.com | joe | 2 | 2021-01-26 21:05:03.2500000 |
| 123 | joe@me.com | joe | 2 | 2021-01-26 21:03:03.2500000 |
| 123 | joe@me.com | joe | 2 | 2021-01-26 21:05:03.2500000 |

I have tried a few different subselects and inner-joins, but I am not able to get a result with all 3 populated. I can provide more sample data if needed

Things I have tried

```
 select a.userEmail, b.*
from (
select *
  from PageViewsTable
    and userEmail is not null
) a join (
  select *
  from PageViewsTable
    and userEmail is null
) b on a.sessionId = b.sessionId


select
  (SELECT top 1
    userEmail
  FROM PageViewsTable b
  WHERE a.sessionId = b.sessionId ) as email
  , *
from PageViewsTable a
```

Comment: What does "row below" mean? The rows in a table have no particular order. Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It suggests helpful things like showing the expected result, what you've tried, ... .

Comment: added what i have tried and cleaned up quesiton

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select coalesce(userid, max(userid) over (partition by sessionid)) as userid,
       coalesce(useremail, max(useremail) over (partition by sessionid)) as useremail,
       coalesce(username, max(username) over (partition by sessionid)) as username,
       . . .
from t;
```

Comment: Never really figured out coalesce, do you need to join all the rows together in some way? Otherwise there are tons of rows

Comment: @IsaacLevin . .  I don't know what you mean.  There are no joins needed in this logic.

Comment: If I just run this I get substantially less rows. I assume this means that there are rows that have all 3 null?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select case when isnull(t1.userId,0) = 0 then t2.userId else   t1.userId end userId,
case when isnull(t1.useremail,'') = '' then t2.useremail else   t1.useremail end useremail,
case when isnull(t1.username,'') = '' then t2.username else   t1.username end username,
t1.sessionId, 
t1.eventTime 
from @tbl t1
inner join (
select 
max(userid) userid, max(useremail) useremail,
max(username) username, max(sessionId) sessionId, max(eventTime) eventTime  from @tbl
group by sessionId ) t2 on t1.sessionId = t2.sessionId
```